# Checkbox Cell and Selectable Cell Table rows

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT 2.4 DataGrid associated with a SingleSelectionModel.  One of the columns in the grid is a CheckboxCell, but it is not used for selection, but to set a boolean field value for the underlying item type of the row.  My problem is that when I click on the checkbox, the row is selected first, then I have to click a second time to set/unset the checkbox.  I would prefer that clicking *outside* of the checkbox does row selection, while clicking *inside* of the checkbox only sets/unsets the checkbox.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this.  I keep coming back to onBrowserEvent, but I'm not sure what to try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches you can do, depending on what exactly you want to do it. Here are the two ideas that come to mind:

- Use a [DefaultSelectionEventManager.CheckboxEventTranslator](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html) to blacklist the column
- Intercept it on a cell by cell basis with [CellPreviewEvent.Handler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/CellPreviewEvent.Handler.html) and handle it on the DOM level by checking the EventTarget (`"click".equals(event.getType())`) and then use `event.stopPropogation()` when the EventTarget is of an input type "checkbox"

Comment: Reading the documentation, it seems like SelectionEventManager has all the tools I need to handle this and other issues I'm having.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This code solved in my case a problemn very similar to yours.

```
Column<SomeBean, Boolean> checkboxColumn= new Column<SomeBean, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell(true,false))
{
    @Override
    public Boolean getValue(SomeBean object)
    {
        if(object == null || object.getId() == null)
           return null;
        return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
    }
};
```