# GWT Celtable: two clicks needed to change checkbox state in FireFox

Tags: firefox, gwt, checkbox, celltable, gwt-celltable

In my project i have CellTable with CheckBoxCell column. This is regular column to represent (change) values and doesn't use for row selection (for selection i use SingleSelectionModel). In Chrome everything works fine, on first click I get checkbox state changed and row selected. In FireFox when I try to click on check box in CheckBoxCell column GWT selects row and after second click on checkbox it change checkbox state. But I need the same behavior as in Chrome (change checkbox state on first click).

Here is how i create column:

```
private <C> Column<T, C> addColumn(CellTable<T> itemListTable, Cell<C> cell, String headerText, int columnWidthPct, final IValueGetter<C, T> getter, @Nullable FieldUpdater<T, C> fieldUpdater) {
    Column<T, C> column = new Column<T, C>(cell) {
        @Override
        public C getValue(T object) {
            return getter.getValue(object);
        }
    };
    column.setFieldUpdater(fieldUpdater);
    column.setSortable(false);
    itemListTable.addColumn(column, headerText);
    itemListTable.setColumnWidth(column, columnWidthPct, PCT);
    return column;
}

private void generateExistingSettingsTable() {
    addColumn(existingSettingsTable, new ParameterizedCheckboxCell<T>(), IS_PUBLIC_HEADER, 10, new IValueGetter<Boolean, T>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean getValue(T setting) {
                    return setting.isPublic();
                }
            },
            new FieldUpdater<T, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void update(int index, T object, Boolean value) {
                    object.setPublic(value);
                    updatePublicState(object);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

My ParameterizedCheckboxCell extends CheckboxCell and overrides only render method (to enable\disable checkbox input).

I already tried everything suggested here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015013/checkbox-cell-and-selectable-cell-table-rows):

- stopPropagation doesn't works for me
- Add column to DefaultSelectionEventManager black list, is not an option (very large area left unclickable around checkbox)

Comment: I have had different behavior with Firefox before. What you can try is add a BeforeSelectionHandler to the row and check if the cell is the one having the checkbox. If yes, just select/unselect it. This should be done of course only for Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i found out today, the same thing happen with Chrome (version 45.0.2454.101).
I investigate this more and find out the following. GWT `CheckboxCell` by default consume only two browser events: `keydown` and `change`. In old Chrome version when you clicked on checkbox `change` event fired and everything works fine. In FireFox and in the new Chrome version there is no `change` event after click (i cannot figure out why, **explanations are welcome**), so i decide to create my own checkbox class that extends `AbstractEditableCell<Boolean, Boolean>` and replace consumed `change` to `click` event. Here is what i got:

```
import java.util.Objects;

import com.google.gwt.cell.client.AbstractEditableCell;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.ValueUpdater;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.InputElement;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlBuilder;

import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.CLICK;
import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.KEYDOWN;

public class ParameterizedCheckboxCell extends AbstractEditableCell<Boolean, Boolean> {

    public ParameterizedCheckboxCell() {
        super(KEYDOWN, CLICK);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, Boolean value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        // Here i have some specific logic so i skip this part
        // You can just copy/paste body of this method from original CheckboxCell
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, Boolean value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<Boolean> valueUpdater) {
        final String type = event.getType();
        final boolean enterPressed = KEYDOWN.equals(type) && event.getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER;
        if (CLICK.equals(type) || enterPressed) {
            InputElement input = parent.getFirstChild().cast();
            Boolean isChecked = input.isChecked();

            if (enterPressed) {
                isChecked = !isChecked;
                input.setChecked(isChecked);
            }

            if (Objects.equals(value, isChecked)) {
                clearViewData(context.getKey());
            } else {
                setViewData(context.getKey(), isChecked);
            }
            valueUpdater.update(isChecked);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEditing(Context context, Element parent, Boolean value) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I skipped `dependsOnSelection` and `handlesSelection` because i dont use this for selection column.